# Knowing the fact that $A^2B=A^2-B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $A$, $B$ two $n \times n$ matrix.

$$A^2B=A^2-B$$
Prove that $$AB=BA$$

I tried solving this problem and, by rewriting the hypotesis conditions and using the properties of invertible matrix I got that
$$A^2B=A^2-B$$
How can I continue from there.

Comment: Are the matrices invertible?

Comment: No, the matrices  are not invertible

Comment: The condition can be rewritten as $(A^2+I)(B-I)=-I$, thus $B=I-(A^2+I)^{-1}$. Can you conclude?

Comment: From the hypothesis, we have
$$A^2(I - B) = B$$
Multiplying both sides on the right formally by $\sum_{k \geq 0} B^{k}$, we get:
$$
A^2 = \sum_{k \geq 1} B^{k}.
$$
Since $B$ clearly commutes with all of its powers, we have at least shown that $B$ commutes with $A^2$.

Comment: @avs That argument only works if the series converges

Comment: $A^2B+B=A^2$ holds, so on taking $A^2$, $B$ times and then shifting it by B don't make a difference, now if somehow I could say this is true for A too, then I could conclude that $AB=BA$...

Comment: @BenGrossmann, sure, that's why I wrote the qualification "formally".

Comment: @Mindlack has solved it by expressing $B$ in terms of powers (positive and negative) of polynomials of $A$.  Such terms all commute with $A$.